# Active link in react router 4

Tags: javascript, sass

I am new to react and learning the routing. I am wondering, how can I use the active class on links. I am using below code but, it is not working.

```
  <ul>
   <li><Link to="about" activeClassName="active">About</Link></li>
   <li><Link to="company" activeClassName="active">Company</Link></li>
   <li><Link to="contact" activeClassName="active">Contact</Link></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Could you specify what have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using router 4 then you need to use  instead of .
You can just use below import statement to get your code work.

```
import { NavLink as Link} from 'react-router-dom';
```